# Disable Program at specific date

Tags: python

So I would like to write a program that disables itself on let's say May 1st.

How would I do that? I was thinking about getting the time with localtime and then writing a "if block" to ask the program if the date is >= to the May 1st. If so it should prompt the user that he can not use the program any longer cause it expired.

But I have a problem writing the if statement, since localtime returns so many values. How would I write the if block?

Comment: How do you prevent someone from altering your [program].py file and subverting the intent of this?  One answer to your question: use epoch seconds.    Determine the drop dead time and date ahead of time, then enforce that.  Call time.time() which gives current epoch seconds, compare the result to your predetermined value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is to convert `datetime` to `date` which you can do by `datetime.datetime.now().date()`, for the `if condtion` you can do something like this:

THis is just an example:

```
import datetime
if datetime.datetime.now().date() >= datetime.date(2012, 1, 15): #insert your date here
    print "True" 
    ...........
    Your Code
    ...........
```

All the Documentation you would ever want on this topic is located here, http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html